# Не добавляется значение в MySQL таблицу

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть такой код:

```
  import mysql.connector
  from config import host, user, password, database
  mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="password",
    database="userlist"
  )

  mycursor = mydb.cursor()

  mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO user (login, password) VALUE ('GG@mail.ru', '123');")
```

1. Почему  `from config import host, user, password, database`  не работает при  `mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=database )`  , выдает ошибку: **argument 1 must be str or None, not tuple**
2. Почему не работает `mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO user (login, password) VALUE ('GG@mail.ru', '123');")`, т.е программа проходит без ошибок, но значение в базу и таблицу не заносятся, хотя если сделать прямой SQL запрос, то все работает нормально.

Comment: 1. Потому что вы в файле config понаставили лишних запятых; 2. Вы уверены, что вы выполняете запрос именно в той базе, в которой ожидаете? Как вы проверяете, что значение не занеслось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Не знаю почему, но починилось само
2. Значение работало, SQL запрос отправлялся, но не сохранялся перед закрытием, для этого нужно использовать `commit()`, в моем случае `mydb.commit()` или сделать авто сохранение `mydb.autocommit = True`, так же в конце написать `mydb.close()`